# If there are many fields in form is it reasonable to create React.useState for each of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with 100 fields for example. I have two ways to deal with it:

1. create useState hook for each of it
2. create one

```
const [field, setField] = React.useState({
  a:"",
  b:"",
  c:"",
  ...
  ...
})
```

and deal with it like so:

```
setField(prev => ({
  ...prev, ...{b: 'Earth Worm Jim'}
}))
```

What is the best/right solution?

Comment: Use a `useReducer` instead! if all the data are highly related.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer you need to read this, if you're working with complex states.

Comment: But useReducer won't make our job easier.

Comment: It seems that when we had this.setState() our life was easier. It seem like hooks in the context only made everything more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a handleChangeInput func like this:

```
const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevStatestate, [name]: value }));
};
```

Here it is important that the name attribute of your jsx, is the same as the state, so a, b or c...

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic setState with useReducer hook like belows

```
const [state, setState] = useReducer((oldState, newState) => ({
    ...oldState, ...newState
}, {
    image: '',
    file: null,
    username: '',
    email: '',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't problem when use useState() but if you want you can use useReduer()
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK_Wqx3RnHk

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html